# How to create a column displaying last recorded peak value in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am trying to create a new column that will list down the last recorded peak values, until the next peak comes along. For example, suppose this is my existing DataFrame:

```
index values
0      10
1      20
2      15
3      17
4      15
5      22
6      20
```

I want to get something like this:

```
index values last_recorded_peak
0      10        10
1      20        20
2      15        20
3      17        17
4      15        17
5      22        22
6      20        22
```

So far, I have tried with np.maximum.accumulate, which 'accumulates' the max value but not quite the "peaks" (some peaks might be lower than the max value).

I have also tried with scipy.signal.find_peaks which returns an array of indexes where my peaks are (in the example, index 1, 3, 5), which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm relatively new to coding, any pointer is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the logic of the fact that it changes back to 17 in row 3?

Comment: The value "peak" at 17 at index 3.. Index 2 and index 4 gives 15, which makes index 3 the peak in the sequence of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) is the way I would go, you just need to work a little bit from the result:

```
from scipy import signal
peaks = signal.find_peaks(df['values'])[0]

df['last_recorded_peak'] = (df.assign(last_recorded_peak=float('nan'))
                              .last_recorded_peak
                              .combine_first(df.loc[peaks,'values'])
                              .ffill()
                              .combine_first(df['values']))
```

---

```
print(df)

     index  values  last_recorded_peak
0      0      10                10.0
1      1      20                20.0
2      2      15                20.0
3      3      17                17.0
4      4      15                17.0
5      5      22                22.0
6      6      20                22.0
```

Comment: Just wondering, if you can do a simple explanation of all the components in this section: (df.assign(last_recorded_peak=float('nan'))
                              .last_recorded_peak
                              .combine_first(df.loc[peaks,'values'])
                              .ffill()
                              .combine_first(df['values']))" part.

Comment: I get the sense that you first assign all values in the newly created column to 'NaN', then fill in the 'values' where the 'peaks' are, but the last part " .ffill()
                              .combine_first(df['values']))" seem to elude my understanding

Comment: `combine_first` is a simple way to add values to a column wherever there is a NaN (matching indices). So the first one is to assign the values from `df.loc[peaks,'values']`. So you'll have NaNs and the corresponding peaks. Then you forward fill. The the initial values (before the first peak) will still be NaNs. That is the purpose of the remaining combine_first :) @qwerty123

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your correcly, your are looking for [`rolling max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

*note: you might have to play around with the `window size` which I set on `2` for your example dataframe*

```
df['last_recorded_peak'] = df['values'].rolling(2).max().fillna(df['values'])
```

**Output**

```
   values  last_recorded_peak
0      10                10.0
1      20                20.0
2      15                20.0
3      17                17.0
4      15                17.0
5      22                22.0
6      20                22.0
```

Comment: I looked up about "rolling" but my peaks may not be spaced neatly at a specific interval, but thanks nonetheless!